# Using Object.entries with Json Objects

Tags: javascript, json

For example, I have some JSON data files like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "kisisel_bilgiler": {
      "isim": "Theredorfin",
      "soyisim": "Endorfinist"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my main JS code for reading the folder and the files inside.

```js
var dosya = {
  bilgi: [],
  sayi: [],
  veri: [],
}

fs.readdir("./bilgiler/kisi-bilgiler/", async (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(async f => {
    dosya.bilgi.push(fs.readFileSync(`./bilgiler/kisi-bilgiler/${f}`))
})
  
  dosya.sayi = files.length;
  console.log(dosya.sayi)
});
```

My goal is to take the data in the files inside the folder, separate them and put them in an `array` and then open the output separately `<div>` in the HTML `<script>` section.

I search a lot but I dont find anything.

Comment: What are you trying to do to the object? What is the desired structure? Where is your JS code?

Comment: "*If I explain as Object.entries I need to make "data" is the key*" - what? Please ask a question.

Comment: What does `Object.entries()` have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "JSON Object" when discussing the data payload that is being moved around. JSON is a string format and once you use the JSON API, specifically [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on that string, you no longer have JSON, you just have a regular JavaScript object or array and work with them as usual.

```js
let json = `{
              "data": {
                        "kisisel_bilgiler": {
                          "isim": "Theredorfin",
                          "soyisim": "Endorfinist"
                        }
                      }
            }`;

let obj = JSON.parse(json); // Parse the object from the string

// You can now access the object via any normal means:

// Via property access:
console.log(obj.data);  // <-- This seems to be the result you were asking for
console.log(obj.data.kisisel_bilgiler);
console.log(obj.data.kisisel_bilgiler.isim);
console.log(obj.data.kisisel_bilgiler.soyisim);

// Via Object.entries:
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.data.kisisel_bilgiler)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Comment: Just to nitpick a little bit. There **is** such a thing like a JSON object. You are completely right that what the OP calls a JSON object, is not a JSON object. However the JSON object is a global object that provides functions such as parse() and stringify(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: @Wimanicesir Yes, you got me on that one. Answer edited for clarity. I think knowing the context in which the term "JSON object" was being used is the key here. The OP (and many other misinformed coders) refer to the *data payload* as a JSON object, which is not a "thing". But yes, within the language construct there is a JSON API.

Comment: @Wimanicesir That's not "nit-picking", thats pedantry of the highest order, and it's not relevant.

Comment: @user229044, It's just for clarity and is more relevant than your comment to attack me.. Don't know what your problem is when you aren't even the one that posted the answer **AND** the one who did already answered and adjusted his answer..